# GNOME control center vanished, nothing on desktop except for background - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, software-center, desktop-icons, gnome-control-center

**GNOME functions suddenly vanished:**

- GNOME control center disappeared and I had to manually reinstall it again.
- Files on desktop are not displayed and I can't interact with it. (e.g. clicking dragging the cursor to select an area doesn't do/display anything). Background image is intact and I can still change it by navigating to the control center(which I just reinstalled) and selecting the image. The files can still be found in the desktop folder.
- I'm suspecting something else might've been broken which is not immediately obvious at this point.

**Worth considering:**

- I previously had some issues with NVIDIA proprietary drivers, but managed to fix it. Even still, from time to time when I update them, my screen turns black with a blinking underscore in the up left corner.
- Alongside with the drivers issues, I had some of the applications not show any UI, but be fully operational. I have been using Ubuntu Wayland since then to avoid this issue.

**Did not work:**

- Switching back to Xorg instead of Wayland.
- update && upgrade then reboot
- Resetting GNOME settings with `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`
- Disabling possible problematic extensions with `gnome-extensions disable --all`
- installing Unity

==============================================

#### Edit:

Turns out I also cannot download files from my browser, whether it is an image or a file. When I press "Save as..." nothing happens.